# How to render math formulas using MathML in Qwt (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, mathml, qwt

On Qwt-6.1.4 there is built-in library for MathML like **qwt_mathml_text_engine.cpp**
And after writing such a code:

```
QwtPlot* plot = new QwtPlot(QwtText("<apply><sin/><ci>x</ci></apply>", QwtText::MathMLText));
ui->gridLayout->addWidget(plot);
```

There is no math special symbols in plot title.[image]

How to make it rendering formulas in proper way using MathML in Qwt?

Comment: Did you remember to call [`QwtText::setTextEngine(QwtText::MathMLText, new QwtMathMLTextEngine())`](https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_text.html#a63e0d6a59a427a37ed0bfa71b782fd76abf479897e4514198246a0b232a597caf)?

Comment: @G.M. No, that's all I have done, I am newbie in qt. So, before the lines I wrote, I should add the line which you proposed, right?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know.  (Note that I haven't used `Qwt` + `MathML` so I'm basically just forwarding what I found in the docs.)

Comment: @G.M. Can you share the link to this documentation?

Comment: @G.M. yes, on your link there is such a text: "To enable MathML support the following code needs to be added to the application:
QwtText::setTextEngine( QwtText::MathMLText, new QwtMathMLTextEngine() );"